# Ember.js - document on mousedown not triggered inside .ember-view

Tags: jquery, ember.js

Using ember.js, i'd like to listen to document mousedown events :

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(){
    //...
});
```

The event is not triggered but not inside the emebr root element (which is not body actually).

What could cause this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eLavixe/1/edit

```
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    //alternatively you can manually hook up in here
  },
  mouseDown: function(){
    alert('mouse down');
  }
});
```